# How to add CORS support on server side of JAX-WS in java

Tags: javascript, java, web-services

I can't find answer to this question
[How to enable CORS on server side of JAX-WS in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435226/how-to-enable-cors-on-server-side-of-jax-ws-in-java?answertab=votes#tab-top)

As Mentionned as response we cann't use the "Handlers" because the first error is about HTTP request (when Javascript request the WSDL). Javascript say "Failed to load http://XXXX/server?wsdl: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://YYYY' is therefore not allowed access.". Because CORS headers is not present.

The request header (with Origin)

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Host:127.0.0.1:11080
Origin:http://10.33.25.15:10080
Referer:http://10.33.25.15:10080/soap/soap.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
```

And the response without CORS header

```
Content-type:text/xml;charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 23 Oct 2017 09:03:51 GMT
Transfer-encoding:chunked
```

How can i "configure" or "customise" Java Endpoint to do this

**EDIT**

I may have found the beginning of a solution, but I do not understand the following error:

Source code ServerInfo.java:

```
@WebService
public class ServerInfo {
    @WebMethod
    public String getServerName() {
        return "Mon Serveur";
    }
}
```

Source code Publisher.java

```
public class Publisher {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        try {
            Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.create(new ServerInfo());
            HttpServer httpServer = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(11080), 0);
            HttpHandler handler = new HttpHandler() {
                @Override
                public void handle(final HttpExchange httpExchange) throws IOException {
                    // TODO CORS
                }
            };
            HttpContext context = httpServer.createContext("/server",handler);
            httpServer.start();
            endpoint.publish(context);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I do not understand this error when running

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: handler already set
at sun.net.httpserver.HttpContextImpl.setHandler(HttpContextImpl.java:86)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.HttpEndpoint.setHandler(HttpEndpoint.java:121)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.HttpEndpoint.publish(HttpEndpoint.java:75)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:241)
at main(Publisher.java:11)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jersey you can create a filter:

```
public class CorsResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter
```

The filter method is where you validate the request and publish the required headers:

```
public void filter (ContainerRequestContext req, ContainerResponseContext containerRsp)
{
    final String origin = req.getHeaderString("Origin");

    if (!isValidOrigin(origin))
        return;

    containerRsp.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
    containerRsp.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS");

    String reqHead = headerValue(req, "Access-Control-Request-Headers");
    if (isNotEmpty(reqHead))
        containerRsp.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", reqHead);

    return;
}
```

Comment: Jersey is for REST not for SOAP?

Comment: Indeed. I did not realized it was about SOAP.